# How to bind the local and Remote data together to Kendo DataSource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I want to bind the Local and Remote Datas to the same Kendo UI Control.
Here I am using Kendo treeview.

[image]

Here First 2 nodes are Hardcoded(Local data) and the third needs to from Database(Remote Data).So now how to handle this.

```
$("#AftermarketTreeView").kendoTreeView({
                            dataTextField: ["text", "text", "MC_ANALYSIS_NAME"],
                            dataSource: {
                                data: [
                                  {
                                      text: "Initiate",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Parts Selection", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Assumptions", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Team", haschildren: false },
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      text: "Analyze",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Part Attributes", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Aftermarket Evaluation", haschildren: false }
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      text: "Monto Carlo",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Monto Carlo", haschildren: true }

                                      ]
                                  }
                                ],
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        hasChildren: "items",
                                        children: {
                                            schema: {
                                                data: "items",
                                                model: {
                                                    hasChildren: "haschildren",
                                                    children: {
                                                        schema: {
                                                            // override the schema.data setting from the parent
                                                            data: function (response) {
                                                                return response;
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        transport: {
                                                            read: {
                                                                url: ResolveUrl("/CreateMaintainAnalysis/GetMontoCarloData/"),
                                                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                                                data:onDataSendAnalysisID,
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

So How to bind it using Kendo TreeView ?

Comment: How is it coded till now? Do you use a datasource for every tree root, can you show a bit more code how your datasource is created and attached to the tree view?

Comment: Right Now I havn't used any DataSource as lack of knowledge on how I can proceed so as of now I have used HardCoded HTML on UI

Comment: Can you then not try to make a concept and post your efforts back so we could help where you get stuck?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/mix-local-data-and-remote-loading

Comment: @ Icepickle, I tried and edited data as above..Now can you help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both a local and remote data source on the same element.  The best option would be a remote data source only and have it return all of the options you're looking for.